# Mylar capacitor and Electrolytic capacitor

Tags: capacitor

Is it a bad practice to use Mylar capacitor and electrolytic capacitor in the same circuit? If so why?

Comment: Have you even bothered to Google what either of those are?

Comment: yes, my understanding is that mylar capacitor the leads doesn't matter if they are connected to negative or positive end. But for electrolytic capacitor the positive and negative leads have to connected to the right terminal

Answer (score 1):

Frequently polyester (Mylar) and electrolytic capacitors are used in the same circuit, usually for different purposes.

Electrolytic capacitors are usually used for power supply filtering, sometimes for coupling and filtering. They are available in compact form with large capacitance such as 1000uF/16V for pennies. A polyester capacitor of that value would be huge and expensive.

Polyester capacitors are used for high frequency filters, for AC snubbers and for audio and some RF circuits. They are usually very low leakage and have moderate dielectric absorption and temperature stability. Lately they are often replaced by ceramic multilayer parts, which have different characteristics again.

At higher frequencies, ceramic parts are used more often.